# Clear cookies from Requests Python

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

I created variable: `s = requests.session()`

how to clear all cookies in this variable?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `Session.cookies` object implements the full [mutable mapping interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping), so you can call:

```
s.cookies.clear()
```

to clear all the cookies.

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.session()
>>> s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set', params={'foo': 'bar'})
<Response [200]>
>>> s.cookies.keys()
['foo']
>>> s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies').json()
{u'cookies': {u'foo': u'bar'}}
>>> s.cookies.clear()
>>> s.cookies.keys()
[]
>>> s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies').json()
{u'cookies': {}}
```

Easiest however, is just to create a new session:

```
s = requests.session()
```

Comment: Note that creating a new session means you won't be able to reuse the connection, so you'll get a slightly slower response.

Comment: You can also delete a specific cookie via `del s.cookies['foo']`