# How to log out of Requests Session in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have successfully logged in to a site using python and sending a POST request with username and password as payload.

When I then go to the same site in a browser, the website informs me that someone is currently logged in to my account (guess who).

My question is this: how do I log out of the request session?

So far I have tried clearing cookies using c.cookies.clear() after finding this question on stackoverflow: [Clear cookies from Requests Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816139/clear-cookies-from-requests-python)

I have verified that cookies are created and then are cleared, but I still run in to the same login duplication when using a browser subsequently.

I have checked the Requests documentation and a number of previous questions, but I can't find an answer.

For you reference, I have pasted a general version of the code below.

Also for you information, when I logout of the browser a GET request is sent. Is this something I need to simluate? I have already tried sending it along with the cookies, but the same result. This seems like something that should be simple. At the moment I can work with it by logging out via browser, but long term it will be pain.

Your assistance is appreciated. Cheers, smaug.

```
import requests

payload = {'userid': 'my username value', 
           'passwd': 'my password value'
}

with requests.Session() a c:
    c.post('http://www.examplewebsite.com/login.html', data = payload)
    print 'cookies', requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(c.cookies)
    c.cookies.clear()
    print 'cookies', requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(c.cookies)
```

Comment: Since this is a "general" form, I'm not sure if this is a typo, but are you really calling `c.cookies.clear` or `c.cookies.clear()`. The former is just retrieving the method on the cookie jar. The latter is actually clearing the jar.

Comment: Well spotted sigmavirus24 - it was just a typo here in this general form, I've amended the code. Cheers.

Comment: That's what I expected. I'm going to try to reproduce this because it sounds like a bug (I'm a requests core developer)

Answer (score 5):

If the website has an API that requires you to logout, `requests` can't possibly know that. You have to explicitly make the `logout` API request.

While `requests` has something called a `Session`, and many web service frameworks do too, a session isn't actually a persistent connection between two computers like a TCP socket.

- A web service framework session is essentially just a way to pass an ID back and forth to the client in cookies and map it to some database record or equivalent. It still only sees one request at a time, and the only way it knows you're done, unless you tell it, is by not seeing your session ID for a while.
- A `requests` session is essentially just a place to store cookies across multiple requests the way a browser would, so web service frameworks' sessions will work the same way they would in a browser.

So, clearing the cookies doesn't do anything that's visible to the server. The server can't see anything you do, except for the requests that you send.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and useful response abarnert.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it sounds, I succeeded in logging out of the session by integrating a sleep statement followed by the get request for the logout page, i.e.:

> ```
> time.sleep(5)
> c.get('http://www.examplewebsite.com/logout.p')
> ```